# How to get the total number of AsyncTasks currently running in parallel in the thread pool?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I need to check the number of AsyncTasks currently executing in parallel before scheduling a fresh AsyncTask so that the fresh task is scheduled only if the number of concurrent tasks is lesser than the maximum pool size.

What is the best way to get the count of all current tasks in the pool?

Answer (score 1):

Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks.

```
 threadPool.getActiveCount()
```